# ros_canopen: virtual joints, is it possible?

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Currently I have three working canopen motor drivers,
**but** my system will consists five motors later (the two missing motors have not been delivered yet).

I have already tested some basic motions based on the five motor system in gazebo, and now i wonder is it possible somehow to test these motions on the real robot.

So, i have a `JointTrajectoryController`, consists of `joint_1`, `joint_2`, `joint_3`, `joint_4`, `joint_5`, and  (`required_drive_mode: 7`)

but in the `driver.yaml` file which is passed to the `canopen_motor_node`, i only link three joints, namely:

```
nodes:
  - name: joint_1
    id: 1
  - name: joint_2
    id: 2
  - name: joint_3
    id: 3
```

**My question is**: is it possible to somehow, virtually, link `joint_4` and `joint_5` to the `canopen_motor_node`?
Because with the current yaml file, i got the error that there is no hardware interface for `joint_4` and `joint_5`.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Ákos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298989/ros_canopen:-virtual-joints,-is-it-possible?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, `canopen_motor_node` does not offer this feature.
Please feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues). Of course a pull request would be welcome as well :)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2018-07-30**:
Hello Mathias! Thanks for the answer, i opened an issue, can you please check if i did/wrote everythink OK? [LINK](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/298).